# Invoke Syscalls from Java

Tags: linux, java

Is there a way to invoke syscalls directly from Java, or is it necessary to first call a native method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use a native method, but you don't need to implement it yourself. Java has a variation on JNI called [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), which lets you access shared libraries directly without needing a JNI interface wrapped around them, so you can use that to interface directly with glibc:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class Test {
    public interface CStdLib extends Library {
        int syscall(int number, Object... args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CStdLib c = (CStdLib)Native.loadLibrary("c", CStdLib.class);

        // WARNING: These syscall numbers are for x86 only
        System.out.println("PID: " + c.syscall(20));
        System.out.println("UID: " + c.syscall(24));
        System.out.println("GID: " + c.syscall(47));
        c.syscall(39, "/tmp/create-new-directory-here");
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, is it possible to use function names instead of numbers?

Comment: @max In the `syscall` interface? No, `syscall` takes an integer to represent the appropriate call to make, just like on the C side. There are a bunch of `#define` s in `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`, like `#define __NR_mkdir 39` to make it easier for people calling the C function, but I don't think there's any way to automatically import those into Java, you'd have to define them all yourself

Comment: Please beware - the numbers on x86 and x86-64 are different on Linux.

Comment: @Maciej Good point, added a warning in the answer

Comment: Great Answer brother! Thanks for your help. From here i have another question. I'll ask it in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to use a native method, or a library that does so for you.