# How can i know which unistd.h file is loaded?

Tags: linux, c, java

I have several `unistd.h` files in my Ubuntu Linux. I've one on `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`. This file has this directives:

```
# ifdef __i386__
#  include "unistd_32.h"
# else
#  include "unistd_64.h"
# endif
```

In that folder, I can find those files (`unistd_32.h` and `unistd_64.h`).

But in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-22/include/asm-generic/` there's another `unistd.h` that starts with this directives:

```
#if !defined(_ASM_GENERIC_UNISTD_H) || defined(__SYSCALL)
#define _ASM_GENERIC_UNISTD_H
```

So, the question is: How can I know which one is loaded? Is there any way to check it in runtime with Java?

Comment: I don't understand the second half of your question: `unistd.h` is a C header file; what has it got to do with Java?

Comment: @Riccardo I would like to make some System Calls, that are defined in that file.

Comment: @user1531 Header files are included as the very first step of compilation, so they are not needed at runtime (you can run code on a system that has no compiler or development environment installed).  Calling C functions from Java is a topic for an [entirely different question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/invoke-syscalls-from-java) - that you seem to have already asked :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The exact rules followed by the `gcc` compiler for finding include files are explained at: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

A quick command-line trick to find out where an include file comes from is the following:<sup>1</sup>

```
echo '#include <unistd.h>' | gcc -E -x c - > unistd.preprocessed
```

Then, if you look at the `unistd.preprocessed` file, you will notice lines like:

```
# 1 "/usr/include/unistd.h" <some numbers>
```

These tell you that the following block of lines (until the next `# number ...` line)
come from file `/usr/include/unistd.h`.

So, if you want to know the full list of files included, you can grep for the `# number` lines:

```
echo '#include <unistd.h>' | gcc -E -x c - | egrep '# [0-9]+ ' | awk '{print $3;}' | sort -u*emphasized text*
```

On my Ubuntu 10.04 / gcc 4.4.3 system, this produces:

```
$ echo '#include <unistd.h>' | gcc -E -x c - | egrep '# [0-9]+ ' | awk '{print $3;}' | sort -u
"<built-in>"
"<command-line>"
"<stdin>"
"/usr/include/bits/confname.h"
"/usr/include/bits/posix_opt.h"
"/usr/include/bits/predefs.h"
"/usr/include/bits/types.h"
"/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h"
"/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h"
"/usr/include/features.h"
"/usr/include/getopt.h"
"/usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h"
"/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h"
"/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"
"/usr/include/unistd.h"
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/stddef.h"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Note:* The search path for include files is modified by
the `-I` command-line option; so, you should add any `-I path`
arguments to the `gcc` invocation.  Also, if you are compiling a C++
source, you should substitute `-x c` with `-x c++`.